# ensure same UPCs in every assortment-group with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a table where Assortments are groups containing multiple products (UPC is the productId). I want to verify that the same UPCs are in each Assortment, but I don't know how to do this.

Here is some test data - we're on SQL Server 2014:

```
--"correct" as each assortment contains the same products
DECLARE @input TABLE (Assortment VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, UPC VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @input (Assortment,UPC)
VALUES ('A','1'),('A','2'),('B','1'),('B','2');

--"not correct" as _not_ each assortment contains the same products
DECLARE @input TABLE (Assortment VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, UPC VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @input (Assortment,UPC)
VALUES ('A','1'),('A','2'),('B','1'),('B','3');
```

My first idea was to count the number of products for each Assortment and check if the count is the same for each Assortment and do the same thing the other way round - checking that the number of Assortments a UPC is in is always the same.

But this does not work in a case like this:

```
DECLARE @input TABLE (Assortment VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, UPC VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @input (Assortment,UPC)
VALUES ('A','1'),('A','2'),('B','3'),('B','4');
```

My next idea was to group by UPC and use a CLR-function to concat all Assortments a UPC is in and compare those for differences, but unfortunately it ignores sort order and by that does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand, I never liked the "FOR XML PATH" syntax and thought there maybe is a better way achieving the same. I used it now anyway, at least it works. :) (updating my post now)

Comment: It's not clear if you're trying to detect a difference in data or in counts, your title refers to the same IDs your question refers to counting number of products - your table has columns named neither Id or Product.

Comment: @Stu Despite being only two sets in my example, there are more than 2 in the real data. (number is unknown) Thanks for your suggestion anyway, I did not use those 2 operators but will look them up.

Comment: Instead of updating your question with the solution you should post it as an answer and then accept the answer. I know it sounds weird but that way your question will have an accepted answer and others know it has been solved. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by using grouping with FOR XML PATH as suggested in the comment from AaronBertrand.

Here is the code I'm using now:

```
DECLARE @input TABLE (Assortment VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, UPC VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @input (Assortment,UPC)
VALUES ('A','1'),('A','2'),('B','1'),('B','2');

DECLARE @grouped TABLE (UPC VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, Assortments VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @grouped (UPC,Assortments)
SELECT UPC, Assortments = STUFF(
      (SELECT N', ' + i2.Assortment
         FROM   @input AS i2
         WHERE  i2.UPC = i.upc
         ORDER BY
                i2.Assortment
         FOR XML PATH(N''),
          TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
FROM @input AS i
GROUP BY
    UPC;

--if this returns something, it is "not correct"
SELECT  g.UPC,
        g.Assortments
FROM    @grouped AS g
WHERE   EXISTS (
    SELECT  g2.Assortments
    FROM    @grouped AS g2
    WHERE   g2.UPC <> g.UPC AND
            g2.Assortments <> g.Assortments
)
```

Edit:
After thinking about it again cross joining DISTINCT Assortments WITH DISTINCT UPCs to get all combinations that should be there and then doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN to @input should also work and avoids the string concatenation.

```
DECLARE @input TABLE (Assortment VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, UPC VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @input (Assortment,UPC)
VALUES ('A','1'),('A','2'),('B','3'),('B','4');

;WITH distinct_upcs AS (
    SELECT  DISTINCT
            i.UPC
    FROM    @input AS i
),
distinct_assortments AS (
    SELECT  DISTINCT
            i.Assortment
    FROM    @input AS i
),
crossed AS (
    SELECT  du.UPC,
            da.Assortment
    FROM    distinct_assortments AS da CROSS JOIN
            distinct_upcs AS du
)
--if this returns something it is "not correct"
SELECT  c.UPC,
        c.Assortment
FROM    crossed AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN
        @input AS i ON
            c.UPC = i.UPC AND
            c.Assortment = i.Assortment
WHERE   i.UPC IS NULL
```